# bash !@#: event not found while using crunch

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create own wordlist, with the following options:

```
crunch 4 4 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}\|'";:/?.>,</ -o out.txt
```

but the result output getting this error: **bash: !@#: event not found**

Comment: The exclamation point is used in history substitution. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to properly escape and quote special characters.

```
command 'abc....}\|'\''".../'
                    ^^        - preserve literal single quote by escaping it
        ^          ^  ^     ^ - put other stuff in single quotes
```

Research "shell quoting" for more info.

Comment: You can't escape a single quote in a single-quoted string in bash.

Comment: Pro tip: you can do it in ansi-C quoting style: `echo $' \' '`